# WordPress get posts by date without query_posts

Tags: posts, query-posts, get-posts

I'm want to get posts from the last 30days in a sidebar but I don't want to use query_posts, is there a way to achieve this with the get posts function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, simple add a filter before you call it and remove it after you do

```
function filter_where_wpa89154($where = '') {
    //posts in the last 30 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where_wpa89154');
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 5,
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => false
); 
$posts = get_posts($args);
remove_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where_wpa89154');
```

notice the `'suppress_filters' => false` which is what makes this happen with `get_posts`

Comment: How would I add this to a loop exactly? I'm a beginner.

Comment: humm that's a whole other question :) in that case i would suggest you use a plugin like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flexible-posts-widget/ or read up on [WP-Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [Widgets_API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)

Answer (score 7):

As of 3.7 you can use date_query http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

So it would look like:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 5,
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) 
    ),
    'suppress_filters' => false
); 
$posts = get_posts($args);
```